# How to join joints ( Armature )?

Tags: armature

I'm new at Blender and I'm trying to make a chibi human character. As the pictures show, I'm trying to join 2 joints. Do you know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I think your illustration could be a little clearer.. to indicate exactly what you mean by 'join joints' to people not familiar with your rig?

Answer (score 1):

The image is unclear. I cannot tell what end of either bone I am looking at.

To make a child bone connect to its parent after parenting, select the child bone, then go to Properties editor -> Bone properties -> Relations panel -> Connected, and check it.

To parent one bone to another in a connected manner, select the desired child bone, then the desired parent bone (so the parent will be active), and strike Ctrl + P. In the appearing Parent menu, click “Connected.”

PS: a child bone’s tail can never truly connect to its parent’s tail.